# C linux proxy server

Tags: c++, c, linux, sockets

I'm trying to build a client -> proxy server -> server application.

I need help with the proxy server, how do i make it send data to the `server` right now it can only communicate with the client.

Here is my codef or the `proxy server`, I modified it from an example. I'm new at this.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     int sockfd, newsockfd, portno, pid;
     socklen_t clilen;
     struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;

     if (argc < 2) {
         fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no port provided\n");
         exit(1);
     }
     sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
     if (sockfd < 0) 
        error("ERROR opening socket");
     bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
     portno = atoi(argv[1]);
     serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
     serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
     serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
     if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,
              sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
              error("ERROR on binding");
     listen(sockfd,5);
     clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
     while (1) {
         newsockfd = accept(sockfd, 
               (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
         if (newsockfd < 0) 
             error("ERROR on accept");
         pid = fork();
         if (pid < 0)
             error("ERROR on fork");
         if (pid == 0)  {
             close(sockfd);
             dostuff(newsockfd);
             exit(0);
         }
         else close(newsockfd);
     } /* end of while */
     close(sockfd);
     return 0; /* we never get here */
}

/******** DOSTUFF() *********************
 There is a separate instance of this function 
 for each connection.  It handles all communication
 once a connnection has been established.
 *****************************************/
void dostuff (int sock)
{
   int n, p;
   char buffer[256];
   char request;
   FILE *file; 
   file = fopen("process.log","a+");

   do
   {
       //here the proxy server receives data from the client
   bzero(buffer,256);
   p = read(sock,buffer,255);
   if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");

   printf("num: %s\n",buffer);

       //here the proxy servers replies to the client.
   n = write(sock,buffer,sizeof(buffer));

       //here the process should send data to the server
       //...codes i need help with...           

   if (n < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");
   fprintf(file,"%s\n",buffer); /*writes*/ 

   }while(p != 0); //this runs the process +1 more than it should. wonder why?

   fclose(file);
}
```

DoStuff() .... you can also check the comments I added.
Also how do I send a message to the client as soon as the client is connected to the server, something like a welcome client message? :)

note: the proxy server sends a GET request to a HTTP 1.1 server.

I would really appreciate it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

To connect to the server, you're going to have to call `socket` and then `connect` to get that socket connected to your real server from the proxy.  See section 5 here:

http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html

Additionally, check `p` instead of `n` 4 lines into your do-while loop in `DoStuff()`.

Comment: I just can't formulate the code can I see an example code of a proxy server? or a server that is being in between a client and a real server?

Comment: Follow the instructions for connecting from a client to a server in order to implement the section you're having issues with above. At the top of the proxy callback, you're going to create a new socket and connect it to your real server, and use that socket to write. Try something, and if you have issues, get back to us with updated code. You can do it! Use the two functions I gave you above, that's literally all there is to it.